# Stanford TokensRegex: how to set normalized annotation using normalized output of NER annotation?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am creating a TokensRegex annotator to extract the number of floors a building has (just an example to illustrate my question). I have a simple pattern that will recognize both "4 floors" and "four floors" as instances of my custom entity "FLOORS". 
I would also like to add a NormalizedNER annotation, using the normalized value of the number entity used in the expression, but I can't get it to work the way I want to:

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
normalized = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

ENV.defaults["ruleType"] = "tokens"

{
  pattern: ( ( [ { ner:NUMBER } ] ) /floor(s?)/ ),
  action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "FLOORS"), Annotate($0, normalized, $$1.text) ) 
}
```

The rules above only set the NormalizedNER fields in the output to the text value of the number, "4" and "four" for the above examples respectively. Is there a way to use the NUMBER entity's normalized value ("4.0" both for "4" and "four") as the normalized value for my "FLOORS" entity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is based on @AngelChang's answer and comment, I'm just posting it here for the sake of ordeliness.

The rule has to be modified so the 2nd Annotate() action's 3rd parameter is `$1[0].normalized`:

```
{
  pattern: ( ( [ { ner:NUMBER } ] ) /floor(s?)/ ),
  action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "FLOORS"), Annotate($0, normalized, $1[0].normalized) ) 
}
```

According to @Angel's comment:

> $1[0].normalized is the "normalized" field of the 0th token of the 1st
>   capture group (as a CoreLabel). The $$1 gives you back the
>   MatchedGroupInfo which has the "text" field but not the normalized
>   field (since that is on the actual token)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "FLOORS"), Annotate($0, normalized, $$1.text) )
```

to

```
action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "FLOORS"), Annotate($0, normalized, $$1.normalized) )
```

Annotate takes three arguments

- arg1 = object to annotate (typically the matched tokens indicated by $0)
- arg2 = annotation field
- arg3 = value (in this case you want the NormalizedNER field instead of the text field)

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work for me. With `$$1.normalized` as you suggested, running on the input "The building has seven floors" yields the following error message:

`Annotating file test.txt {
    Error extracting annotation from seven floors
  } `
And the output XML doesn't contain `<NormalizedNER>` tags for the tokens of "_seven floors_" as expected. Do you know what could be wrong? I'm using Stanford CoreNLP version 3.5.2.

Comment: Also, could you please direct me to where I can find more information on the possible 3rd arguments of Annotate()? Your [Javadoc page for TokensRegex expressions](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/tokensregex/types/Expressions.html) doesn't list `$$n.normalized` (perhaps it needs updating?)

Answer (score 0):

> With $$1.normalized as you suggested, running on the input "The
>   building has seven floors" yields the following error message:
>   Annotating file test.txt { Error extracting annotation from seven
>   floors }

It might be because the `NamedEntityTagAnnotation` key is not already present for the token represented by `$$1`.  I suppose, before running TokensRegex, you'd want to make sure that your numeric tokens - either "four" or "4" in this case - have the corresponding normalized value - "4.0" in this case - set to their `NamedEntityTagAnnotation` key.

> Also, could you please direct me to where I can find more information
>   on the possible 3rd arguments of Annotate()? Your Javadoc page for
>   TokensRegex expressions doesn't list $$n.normalized (perhaps it needs
>   updating?)

I believe, that what `$$n.normalized` would do, would be to retrieve the value which, in Java code, would be the equivalent of `coreLabel.get(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class)` where `coreLabel` is of type `CoreLabel` and corresponds with `$$n` in TokensRegex.
This is because of the following line in your TokensRegex: `normalized = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation" }`

Comment: Thanks @omer-hassan. I'm not sure I understand your 1st comment. Could you please supply code?

Btw, "four" and "4" do have normalized annotations from Stanford NER (via its NUMBER entity resolver), which I use as an annotator in addition to my TokensRegex annotator. This is the properties file I use when invoking `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP`:

`annotators=tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,my_entities,parse
customAnnotatorClass.my_entities=edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexAnnotator
my_entities.rules=my_entities.rules`

(`my_entities.rules` contains the rules in my question.)

Comment: @mmihaltz So you have this: `action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "FLOORS"), Annotate($0, normalized, $$1.normalized) )`  Here, `$$1` represents a token.  `.normalized` represents the `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation` class.  In Java code, `$$1.normalized` would translate to: `coreLabel.get(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class)`, where `coreLabel` is of type `CoreLabel` and is represented by `$$1` in the TokRegex.  (Cont. in next comment:)

Comment: @mmihaltz  Now, the `CoreLabel` object is a bit like a `Map` object. If you do `coreLabel.get(NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class)`, then you have to have previously done `coreLabel.put(NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class, someValue)` at some point. So if you're getting this message: `{Error extracting annotation from seven floors }` then I can only surmise that maybe you're trying to retrieve the value for some key from a CoreLabel when no such key exists for that CoreLabel.

Comment: Sorry, in this case, you want 
$1[0].normalized

this is the "normalized" field of the 0th token of the 1st capture group (as a CoreLabel).  The $$1 gives you back the MatchedGroupInfo which has the "text" field but not the normalized field (since that is on the actual token).

Comment: ^^ Ok so that's probably what's causing your problem. I wasn't sure about the difference between `$1` and `$$1`

Comment: Thanks @Angel, $1[0].normalized worked with my rule & example. I'll post an answer.